# iterate with fold_right in Ocaml

Tags: ocaml

fold_right gives me values starting from the tail of the list but I want to give a function to fold_right as a parameter such that this function would collect values starting from the head of the list .
I want `iter`to receive values starting with the head of the list.

Continous Passing is the keyword ... .Another way to ask the question would be how to`fold_left`with `fold_right`

```
let fold f ls acc = List.fold_right f ls acc

val iter : ('a -> unit) -> 'a t -> unit

let iter f my_type =  
    let rec iiter my_type return = 
        return (fold (fun x y -> f x) my_type ()) () in iiter my_type (fun x y -> ())
```

But when I call :

```
iter (fun a -> print_string a) ["hi";"how";"are";"you"];;
```

Output:

> youarehowhi

I need

> hihowareyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let fold_left f init ls =
        let res = List.fold_right (fun a b acc -> b (f acc a)) ls (fun a -> a)
        in res init
```

now calling

`fold_left (fun a b -> Printf.printf "%s\n" b) () ["how";"are";"you"];;`

gives us

> how
>
> are
>
> you

Answer (score 1):

This is quite simple, you must try to match the signatures for the behavior.

Iteration takes no input, and returns `unit`, while folding takes an input and returns an output of the same type. Now, if the input taken by folding is `unit` then you'll have a folding function which applies a function on each element of a collection by passing an additional `unit` and returning an `unit`, which basically corresponds to the normal iteration, eg:

```
# let foo = [1;2;3;4;5];;
# List.fold_left (fun _ a -> print_int a; ()) () foo;;
12345- : unit = ()
```

As you can see the fold function just ignores the first argument, and always returns `unit`.

Comment: I am not allowed to use fold_left :) , otherwise I would've done it, I must use only fold_right and iterate starting with the head , not tail

Comment: @Oleg: left fold can be implemented in terms of right fold and vice versa; see [this Haskell article](https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldl_as_foldr) (note: the order of arguments to foldr are different between Haskell and OCaml)

Comment: @newacct
I would also like to ask if my question above is understandable

Answer (score 1):

The continuation that you need to pass through `fold` in this case is a function that will, once called, iterate through the rest of the list.

EDIT: like so:

```
let iter f list = fold
  (fun head iter_tail -> (fun () -> f head;; iter_tail ()))
  list
  ()
```

Answer (score 1):

fold_left is like List.fold_left but constructed with List.fold_right (Not tail-recursive):

```
let fold_left f a l = List.fold_right (fun b a -> f a b) (List.rev l) a ;;
```

Is not a good idea, because fold_left is not tail-recursive and List.fold_left is tail-recursive. Is better to produce a fold_right (tail-recursive) as :

```
let fold_right f l a = List.fold_left (fun a b -> f b a) a (List.rev l) ;;
```

If you can't use List.rev :

```
let rev l =
  let rec aux acc = function
    | []    -> acc
    | a::tl -> aux (a::acc) tl
  in
  aux [] l
;;
```

iter use fold_left :

```
let iter f op = ignore (fold_left (fun a b -> f b;a) [] op ) ;;
```

Test :

```
# fold_left (fun a b -> (int_of_string b)::a ) [] ["1";"3"];;
- : int list = [3; 1]
# rev [1;2;3];;
- : int list = [3; 2; 1]
# iter print_string  ["hi";"how";"are";"you"];;
hihowareyou- : unit = ()
```

Comment: hi , thanks for your answer, but I am not allowed to use List.rev

Comment: @Oleg. I have add rev in my response (it is not difficult to write). Have a good day.